# Affix a row to the bottom of the screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap `.row` with some nav controls on it.

I want it to sit directly underneath the content that is above it, unless that pushes it off the screen.

In that case, I wait it to stay affixed to the bottom of the screen. Other content might be behind it, but you would be able to scroll the page down without the controls moving.

Is this doable with Bootstrap's `affix` plugin? Would another approach be more suitable?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding a class of "navbar-fixed-bottom" to the nav like so :

You will then have to add padding to your body or container, depending on your set up, like:
       body > .container {
            padding-top: 60px;
        }

Here is an example:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Also you should not put .row on the same element as you "nav controls on"

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to extend this to allow the footer to float upward if the page has empty space?

Comment: You could always change the CSS of the footer and the body padding, depending on how much "empty space" you have.However, the tricky part is to calculating the height of the empty space. If you give me a link, maybe I can come up with a solution.